# res.render() not working from axios request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, axios

I have two axios requests: one to get the data from the API and then another to send the received data to a view route.

```
    const res = await axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/shifts/summary',
        data: {
            from,
            to,
            client,
            cleaner,
            field,
        },
    });

    if (res.data.status === 'success') {
        showAlert('success', 'Running summary');
        window.setTimeout(async () => {
            await axios({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/summary_results',
                data: {
                    summary: res.data,
                },
            });
        }, 1500);
```

The data gets passed correctly into the view route, however the res.render() does not display/render the new page:

```
exports.summaryResults = (req, res, next) => {
    res.status(200).render('summary_results', {
        title: 'Summary results',
        summary: req.body.summary,
    });
};
```

I do not receive any errors at all. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

what templating engine are you using? and have configured the express to use the template engine?
i.e
`app.set("view engine", "pug"); app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));`
where views is the name of the directory where you have your templates

Comment: Yes I am using pug and have configured it exactly as you said. All my other views work, so it is definitely not the configuration. Could it be the fact that I am sending a POST request with the data to the view?

Comment: No, confirm that you have a `summary_results` file

Comment: I wish misspelling was the problem but no. I cannot render any view or even redirect from that method. I think I have to find another way of passing the data from the api to the view.

Comment: I still don't think it is the data, did you setup a route for the summaryResults controller? like `router.get("/summary", summaryResults)`if there is a router, try sending dummy data from the render method, if you can see the dummy data on the browser, then the issue is from the data coming from the POST request

Comment: Yes I have a route and I know it triggers the method because a console log returns the correct data that was inputted. In the network inspector, I can actually see my page being returned with all the correct data. However, the current page I am on does not refresh or go the new route no matter what I do.